# PHP Statistic Functions PECL stats

Tags: php, apache2, debian, pecl

I installed the PECL stats package for my Apache2 webserver. I used both `pecl list` and `phpinfo()` to confirm that stats were installed.

For some reasons, in my php code I couldn't use some Statistic Functions that listed on PHP documentation.

These functions work well:

- `echo stats_cdf_normal(1.96, 0, 1, 1);`
- `echo stats_cdf_exponential( 3 , 2 , 1 );`

But these are not (which I need for my program):

- `echo stats_rand_gen_normal(9,1);`

.....

- `all stats_rand_gen...;`

And I got this error on my browser: `No data received`

Not sure where the problem comes from. I am really appreciated if someone can help me out.

Comment: Check Apache error log first to get the specific error.

Comment: This is the Apache error I found:
"INITGN called before random number generator  initialized -- abort!"

I am not sure what it means...

Comment: And now search gives me [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57830).

Answer (score 0):

This drove me nuts for hours! I finally found someone had patched the bug [here](https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=57830&patch=fix_randlib.c_add_static&revision=latest) and after applying the static declarations, it was just a matter of recomputing the MD5 hash and then recompiling the PECL extension. I prepared a repo [here](https://github.com/admonkey/stats-1.0.3-patch) with a short README to install.

If you don't already have them, then these dependencies are required:
Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-mysql gcc libpcre3-dev build-essential php-pear`

Basically, you will need to uninstall the one you have now:
`sudo pecl uninstall stats`

Clone repository with patch already applied:
`git clone https://github.com/admonkey/stats-1.0.3-patch.git`
if you can't use git, then you can just download the source code and unzip it.

Move into source folder:
`cd stats-1.0.3-patch`

compile/install extension
`sudo pecl install package.xml`

restart apache
`sudo service apache2 restart`